# why slick2.0 can not find the TableQuery class in playframework 2.2.1?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

My model is:

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery


class User(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String)](tag, "User") {
def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey)
def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
def street = column[String]("STREET")
def * = (id, name, street)
}

//val users = TableQuery[Users]
val users=TableQuery[User]
```

I do this follow the example on

http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1-RC1/gettingstarted.html#slick-examples

when I compile the error is:

```
[myslickclick] $ compile
[info] Compiling 9 Scala sources and 1 Java source to C:\assigment\myslickclick\
target\scala-2.10\classes...
[error] C:\assigment\myslickclick\app\model\User.scala:15: expected class or obj
ect definition
[error] val Users=TableQuery[User]
[error] ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 03/03/2014 3:55:49 PM
```

I use slick 2.0.1 rc1. I think it is same, but there is still can not recognize the class.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you cannot declare values outside of classes or objects.

Your `val users=TableQuery[User]` should be in an object, like a `UserDAO`:

```
object UserDAO {
  val users = TableQuery[User]

  def all: ...

  def byId: ...
}
```